# How to update _id of all documents in a collection in mongo using node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a requirement that I want to update all documents' id values. I know how to update only one document of a collection. But how can I update all documents?

```
db name - mydb
collection name - customers
documents - many....

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1d814ac488402bcf1600b3"),
    "name" : "Company Inc",
    "address" : "Highway 37"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1d9176bd5be834bf328384"),
    "name" : "Company Inc 10",
    "address" : "Highway 37"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1d9176bd5be834bf328385"),
    "name" : "Company Inc 11",
    "address" : "Highway 37"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1d9176bd5be834bf328386"),
    "name" : "Company Inc 12",
    "address" : "Highway 37"
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1d9176bd5be834bf328387"),
    "name" : "Company Inc 13",
    "address" : "Highway 37"
}
etc.,
```

Here i just want to update in all documents `_id` value. For each document, I need to update id as given input from array. I just simply tried to pass `i++` as value. It's not working.

```
var mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

mongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("mydb");
  var collection = dbo.collection("customers");
  var customers = collection.find().toArray();
  var bulkArray = [];
  customers.forEach(function* (d, i) {
    bulkArray.push({ updateOne: { filter: { _id: mongodb.ObjectID(d._id) }, 
        update: { $set: { _id:  i++ }}, upsert:true }});
  });
 collection.bulkWrite(bulkArray, {ordered:true, w:1});
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to change the `_id`?

Comment: we have requirement to update ids

Comment: That's not really a reason.

Comment: In mongodb you cannot directly update `_id` via `$set` and update operations. The workaround is to remove (old doc) and insert with new desired `_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
db.customers.aggregate([{ $group: { _id: '', data: { $push: '$$ROOT' } } }, {
    $project: {
        data: {
            $map:
            {
                input: "$data",
                as: "each",
                in: { $mergeObjects: ['$$each', { '_id': { $indexOfArray: ['$data', '$$each'] } }] }
            }
        }
    }
}, { $unwind: '$data' }, { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$data' } }, { $out: "customersNew" }])
```

**Collection Data from customers :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1d814ac488402bcf1600b3"),
    "name" : "Company Inc",
    "address" : "Highway 37"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1d9176bd5be834bf328384"),
    "name" : "Company Inc 10",
    "address" : "Highway 37"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1d9176bd5be834bf328385"),
    "name" : "Company Inc 11",
    "address" : "Highway 37"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1d9176bd5be834bf328386"),
    "name" : "Company Inc 12",
    "address" : "Highway 37"
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1d9176bd5be834bf328387"),
    "name" : "Company Inc 13",
    "address" : "Highway 37"
}
```

**Result written to customersNew collection :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "name" : "Company Inc",
    "address" : "Highway 37"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "name" : "Company Inc 10",
    "address" : "Highway 37"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "name" : "Company Inc 11",
    "address" : "Highway 37"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "name" : "Company Inc 12",
    "address" : "Highway 37"
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "name" : "Company Inc 13",
    "address" : "Highway 37"
}
```

Not exactly sure why this is needed.

1. Anyhow you can't update `_id` of an existing document unless you
   delete that doc & insert it back with new required `_id`.
2. Instead of reading all docs from DB, deleting & rewriting
       all back to collection would be two or three way call to DB & that
       too for this large amount of data it can be worrisome.
3. You can try this query, but be cautious on it the final stage [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) - it
           would write the aggregation output to collection name specified (**Do not specify name of existing collection - unless needed/tested**) !!
           You verify the data being written by removing `$out` stage & then use
           `$out` to write data to new collection, Once you're good with data in new
           collection drop the old one & rename new one (`customersNew`) to
           `customers`.
4. If this aggregation fails to memory limit you might need to use
       `allowDiskUse: true`  [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry for late reply .. i have tried same as you mentioned. i am not getting any output.

Comment: What do you mean by not getting any output? It will create a new collection

Comment: it will create new collection while trying in mongo. i am trying with nodejs. so its not creating collection

Comment: @Learner : I've tried it using `nodejs - mongoose` & also with `nodejs - mongo-driver`, with both of those it's working as expected. What is the issue that you're looking at ?

Comment: i am not getting any output. its simply shows console nothing

Comment: its working as expected. i have added last .each(function(err, doc) {
            if (doc) {
                console.log(doc);
                db.close();
                // Got a document, terminate the each
                return false;
            }
        });